# Any way to use function name stored in a table in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table in which different operations should apply to different columns.

Let's call it `A`:

```
foo | bar | baz
---------------
   0|    1|   2
   3|    4|   5
```

Now let's say have a table `B`

```
columnname|operation
--------------------
       foo|  f_add_1
       bar|f_times_2
       baz|f_minus_3
```

Where there exist SQL UDFs corresponding to each entry in `B.operation` which we could normally call likewise: `SELECT f_add_1(2)` = `3`.

Is there a way to compose, in pure Redshift-flavored SQL, these two tables to produce a table `C` where the operation in table `B` is applied to the value in table `A`:

```
foo | bar | baz
---------------
   1|    2|  -1
   4|    8|   2
```

In reality my "table A" would have millions of rows, and my "table B" would have maybe 10 operations corresponding to hundreds or thousands of columns.

I could of course do this with a wrapping script, but it would be real neat to do this whole thing in one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Amazon Redshift stored procedure can construct a text string that contains a command, which can then be passed to the `EXECUTE` command. So, yes, it would be possible to call an appropriate function based upon the content of a row.

However, it isn't possible to simply say "insert the value of this column into the SQL query and run the matching stored procedure". Instead, the stored procedure would need to be called specifically for each row via a separate query. This would be very inefficient given that the table has millions of rows.

If there are a limited number of possible operations, a better approach would probably be:

- For each distinct operation:

  - Run an SQL query that performs the operation `WHERE operation = desired_operation`

Therefore, if there are 5 distinct operations, it would require 5 separate queries to run, each of which operates on many rows.

Comment: Yup that option 2 was what I was thinking as a fallback. It seems raw Postgres has an eval() function, but it doesn't surprise me that Redshift wouldn't implement this.